# What are numerical algorithms to compute the maximum of a function which depends on many parameters?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

Let's say I have a function $f$ that I want to maximize. This function depends on many parameters $p_1, p_2, \dots, p_n$ (where $n > 20$). However, one parameter is a function of all the other parameters, e.g., $p_1 = p_1(p_2,\dots, p_n)$.

What are numerical algorithms to determine the maximum of $f$? I can provide certain boundaries on the parameters.

Comment: Then you only need to maximize a function of $n-1$ parameters, namely the function $g(p_2,\dots,p_n) = f\bigl(p_1(p_2,\dots,p_n),p_2,\dots,p_n\bigr)$.

Comment: Those are variables, not parameters. What can you tell us about $f$? Is it polynomial, at least?

Comment: Are the $p_i$ variables or parameters ? $f(\text{what ?})$

Comment: [SciPy optimization](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) offers a dozen of multivariate optimization methods. Listing them here doesn't seem useful. The choice is based on the behavior of the function and the structure of constraints if any.